# ¿Como crear un delete trigger en SQL Server2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tengo un tabla llamada `Productos` en la que quiero crear un trigger el cual no permita eliminar un registro cuando la existencia de dicho producto sea mayor que `0`

He probado con lo siguiente:

```
go

create trigger ProductoExistencia

on Productos for delete as

if((select Existencias from Productos) = 0)

delete from Productos inner join deleted on Productos.Id_Producto=deleted.Id_Producto 

else begin
raiserror('Cantidad mayor que cero',16,1)
rollback transaction

end
go
```

Pero no me ha dado resultado.

Comment: y no te dio resultado por qué???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Opción principal: Lanzar un error si se trata de borrar un productos con `Existencias > 0`**

Con un `IF EXISTS` puedes verificar si al menos uno de los registros que está a punto de ser borrado tiene el valor de `Existencias` mayor a cero. Si es el caso, lanzas un error para impedir el `delete`. Si no, no hay necesidad de hacer nada, y el `delete` ejecutará con éxito.

```
create trigger ProductosDeleteTrigger
on Productos after delete as
begin
    if exists(select null
                from deleted
               where Existencias > 0)
    begin
        raiserror('Cantidad mayor que cero',16,1);
        rollback transaction;
        return;
    end;
end;
go
```

**Opción alternativa: Ignorar el delete de productos con `Existencias > 0`**

Otra opción es de, al hacer un `delete`, en vez de lanzar un error al encontrar un registro con `Existencias > 0`, de simplemente pasar por alto ese registro, no borrarlo y continuar borrando los registros que sí se pueden borrar.

Personalmente, no me parece buena idea hacerlo de esta manera ya que ese comportamiento no es intuitivo y puede causar confusión.

Pero ya que *parece* que esa es la opción que está presentando @Flxtr en su respuesta, aprovecho para incluir la manera correcta de hacerlo.

La manera de hacerlo es usando un `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
create trigger ProductosDeleteTrigger
on Productos instead of delete as
begin
  delete p
    from dbo.Productos p
    join deleted d
      on d.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
     and d.Existencias = 0;
end;
go
```

A diferencia de los triggers normales que se ejecutan *adicionalmente* a la sentencia que provocan su ejecución, los `INSTEAD OF` triggers *reemplazan* la sentencia.

Comment: Sabes, podria funcionar, lo probare :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear el `Trigger` y realizar directamente el `DELETE`, si el registro existe se elimina:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ProductoExistencia
    ON Productos
    FOR DELETE
AS
DELETE Productos
    FROM DELETED D
    INNER JOIN Productos T ON T.Id_Producto = D.Id_Producto AND T.Existencias > 0
GO
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

En la sentencia del `DELETE` se agrega `AND T.Existencias > 0` para cumplir con la validación que es necesaria

Comment: El servidor me dice que hay un erro de sintaxis cerca de "inner", no me deja enlazar las tablas para hacer la eliminacion del registro y por supuesto, tampoco puedo crear el trigger.

Comment: Acabo de crear una tabla llamada `Productos`, creé el `Trigger` tal cual lo puse y el script corre a la perfección, Toma como base el `Trigger` que puse de ejemplo y si se vuelve a generar otro error lo checamos

Comment: Tu script es basico y no dudo que funcione a la perfeccion, pero el problema es como colocar la condicion de que unicamente se puedan borrar los productos que tengan existencia=0.

Comment: Bien, ya entendí el punto, edité mi respuesta agregando `AND T.Existencias > 0`

Comment: Esto no va a funcionar. Seguirá borrando todos los registros por igual. Creo que tal vez tenías en mente usar un `INSTEAD OF` trigger. Pero aun de ser ese el caso, la condición con `Existencias` no es la correcta.